# String(byte array) to byte array

Tags: java, string, arrays

i need to convert from string to same byte array:

```
String data = request.getParameter("data");

byte[] dataByte = new byte[]{};

data = -60,-33,-10,-119,126,114,-61,-31,55,-102,-35,-72,114,77,115,72,79,-117,102,64,98,-20,-75,27,58,-59,86,-97,106,19,-112,-79,100,105,115,107,100,105,114,101,99,116,111,114,95,115,97,102,101,46,99,111,110,102,105,103,49,52,53,53,83,112,97,99,101,115,83,116,111,114,101,114,117,99,111,110,116,101,110,116,85,114,108,61,115,116,111,114,101,58,47,47,50,48,49,50,47,49,48,47,49,47,57,47,53,50,47,57,100,48,48,48,48,55,97,45,54,50,48,48,45,52,54,52,102,45,97,48,48,97,45,50,52,97,100,52,98,100,55,50,53,53,48,46,98,105,110,124,109,105,109,101,116,121,112,101,61,97,112,112,108,105,99,97,116,105,111,110,47,111,99,116,101,116,45,115,116,114,101,97,109,124,115,105,122,101,61,52,53,57,53,49,124,101,110,99,111,100,105,110,103,61,85,84,70,45,56,124,108,111,99,97,108,101,61,114,117,95,124,105,100,61,52,49,48,56,101,57,100,100,50,100,56,45,56,102,54,97,45,52,54,55,54,45,56,53,99,57,45,50,52,54,102,55,57,57,55,101,102,48,99,77,111,110,32,79,99,116,32,48,49,32,48,57,58,53,50,58,49,53,32,78,79,86,83,84,32,50,48,49,50,119,111,114,107,115,112,97,99,101,97,100,109,105,110,97,100,109,105,110
```

Comment: `split(",")` then `Byte.parseByte()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] dataArray = data.split(",")
```

You can then iterate over that `dataArray` and then create `byte[]` out of it.

```
    String dataArray[] = data.split(",");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[dataArray.length];
    int count = 0;
    for(String str : dataArray)
    {
        bytes[count++] = Byte.parseByte(str);
    }
```

If you know character encoding then you can use [#String.getBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Comment: `String.getBytes()` semantics is quite different from what I suspect the OP wants and you indicate with your code fragment - that will give  you the `byte` representation of the string, not the byte values that are comma-separated!

Comment: Problem is it is not clear how he has obtained that `data` string. If he wants to convert exact sequence then solution 1 will work. But it can be a simple print of byte[] which was created from string. That is why I have added second point.

Answer (score 0):

[String.getBytes(String charsetName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) will give you a byte-array. You will have to be careful re. specifying your character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringTokenizer or String.split() method and parse each substring to byte. Take care with encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` and iterate over the resulting array:

```
String[] array = data.split(",");
byte[] dataByte = new byte[ array.length ];
for ( int i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++ ) { dataByte[ i ] = Byte.parseByte( array[ i ] ); }
```

Cheers,

Comment: It's not clear, but I'm not convinced that the OP is getting a comma-separated string. I think that's more likely an illustration of the info they want

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String#getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) method for this purpose: -

```
String data = request.getParameter("data");
byte[] dataByte = data.getBytes()
```

It uses the `default character encoding`.. You can specify your own..

See [String#getBytes(Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Or you can use [Byte#parseByte(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String%29) method in each value of the string array after splitting it: -

```
    String data = request.getParameter("data");
    String arr[] = data.split(",");
    byte[] newarr = new byte[arr.length];

    int count = 0;
    for (String val: arr) {
        newarr[count++] = Byte.parseByte(val);
        System.out.println(Byte.parseByte(val) + ", ");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP wants - this would give you the byte representation of the string, not the `byte` representation of the values separated by commas in the string...